# Casting base type with Java

Tags: java

Say I have a base class:

```
abstract class TheBase {}

class Foo extends TheBase {}
class Bar extends TheBase {}
```

And I want to "cast" the base object into this type:

```
TheBase obj = getFromSomewhere();

Foo foo = obj.asA(Foo.class);

Bar bar = obj.asA(Bar.class);
```

`asA` will throw an exception I have defined like: `CustomCannotCastException()`

Is this possible?

Comment: At first, don't do the cast in the TheBase class. Let the caller decide, which Class you get

Comment: @JordiLaforge: But the caller is deciding which class she wants (by means of the parameter).

Comment: Why re-invent the standard casting mechanism? Why not just do `Foo foo = (Foo)obj;`? Why your own `CustomCannotCastException` instead of using the standard `ClassCastException`?

Comment: @Thilo, thats true, but: So TheBase "knows" that there are subclasses because of the existence of the Method, and in my solution the subclasses can "override" the casting-behavior and maybe throw more specific exeptions with more info.

Comment: @Thilo: And one more: Normally such "wanted" behavior end up in constructors for adapters. My implementation is much easy to change, because the behavior is in the specific subclass.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
public class TheBase {
    public <T> T asA(Class<T> claxx) {
        if (claxx.isInstance(this)) {
            return claxx.cast(this);
        } else {
            throw new CustomCannotCastException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I faintly remember that this pattern (the "self-casting class") had a name. Can you help me out?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know if this is a named pattern.

Comment: Maybe you mean "Downcasting", it's a codesmell: http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2006/12/26/downcasting-is-a-code-smell/

Answer (score 1):

```
if(obj instanceof Foo)
{
    Foo foo = (Foo)obj;
}

if(obj instanceof Bar)
{
    Bar bar = (Bar)obj;
}
```

Comment: I need that the 'asA' method throws my own custom exception that is why I can't do direct casting like this one

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't put the asA-Method in the TheBase-Class.
I would prever a code, which looks like this:

```
TheBase obj = getFromSomewhere();
Foo foo = Foo.getInstance(obj);
Bar bar = Bar.getInstance(obj);
```

//Example for FOO

```
 public Foo getInstance(TheBase aBaseSomething) {
        if (aBaseSomething instanceof Foo) {
            return (Foo)aBaseSomething;
        } else {
            throw new CustomCannotCastException();
        }
    }
```

So the needed subclass can decide, what to do, and the superclass doesn't need to know that there are subclasses.

Comment: @Flavio's solution does not need a list of all classes.

Comment: but @PCs solution would need it. Anyway, the superclass shouldn't know, that there are any subclasses.